# Flutter 3.0.3: Google Maps causes app to crash

Tags: flutter, dart, google-maps

Is there any issue with Google Maps for Flutter? Since upgrading to flutter 3.0.0 & now 3.0.3 from 2.10.3 Google Maps causes the app to crash and this happens without any error log as to what the cause of the crash is. This only happen on the 'AddAddressScreen' which is where the map is used. It attempts to load the Map Interface and then crashes automatically without any further information as what the cause of the crash is.

I also tried capturing the crash using crashlytics by Google and i'm still unable to find what the cause of the crash is.

Prior to this upgrade, the app worked perfectly on flutter 2.10.3.

I need help if anyone knows a work around

Kindly Find below the code:

```
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';

class AddAddressScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const AddAddressScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<AddAddressScreen> createState() => _AddAddressScreenState();
}

class _AddAddressScreenState extends State<AddAddressScreen> {
  TextEditingController _addressController = TextEditingController();
  late bool _isLoggedIn;
  CameraPosition _cameraPosition =
      CameraPosition(target: LatLng(9.072264, 7.491302), zoom: 17);
  late Position position;
  LatLng _initialPosition = LatLng(9.072264, 7.491302);
  bool locationLoaded = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // _getUserCurrentPosition();

    _isLoggedIn = Get.find<AuthController>().userIsLoggedIn();
    if (_isLoggedIn && Get.find<UserController>().userModel == null) {
      Get.find<UserController>().getUserInfo();
    }

    if (Get.find<LocationController>().addressList.isNotEmpty) {
      double lat =
          double.parse(Get.find<LocationController>().getAddress["latitude"]);
      double lng =
          double.parse(Get.find<LocationController>().getAddress["longitude"]);

      //set saved user address to camera position
      _cameraPosition = CameraPosition(target: LatLng(lat, lng), zoom: 17);

      //set initial position to saved user address
      _initialPosition = LatLng(lat, lng);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: TitleTextWidget(
            titleText: 'Add Address', titleColor: AppStyles.appSecondaryColor),
        leading: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            Get.back();
          },
          child: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back_outlined,
              color: AppStyles.appSecondaryColor),
        ),
        backgroundColor: AppStyles.appPrimaryColor,
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: GetBuilder<LocationController>(builder: (locationController) {
        return SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Container(
                  height: SizeConfig.height140,
                  width: double.maxFinite,
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                      left: SizeConfig.width5,
                      right: SizeConfig.width5,
                      top: SizeConfig.height5),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(SizeConfig.radius5),
                      border: Border.all(
                          width: 2, color: AppStyles.appPrimaryColor)),
                  child: Stack(
                    children: [
                      GoogleMap(
                          initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
                              target: _initialPosition, zoom: 17))
                    ],
                  )),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                    left: SizeConfig.width20, top: SizeConfig.height20),
                child: SizedBox(
                  height: SizeConfig.height50,
                  child: ListView.builder(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                      itemCount: locationController.addressTypeList.length,
                      itemBuilder: ((context, index) {
                        return InkWell(
                          onTap: () {
                            locationController.setAddressTypeIndex(index);
                          },
                          child: Container(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                horizontal: SizeConfig.width20,
                                vertical: SizeConfig.width20),
                            margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: SizeConfig.width10),
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              borderRadius:
                                  BorderRadius.circular(SizeConfig.radius5),
                              color: Theme.of(context).cardColor,
                              boxShadow: [
                                BoxShadow(
                                    color: Colors.grey.shade300,
                                    spreadRadius: 1,
                                    blurRadius: 5)
                              ],
                            ),
                            child: Icon(
                              index == 0
                                  ? Icons.home_filled
                                  : index == 1
                                      ? Icons.work_outlined
                                      : Icons.location_on_outlined,
                              color:
                                  locationController.addressTypeIndex == index
                                      ? AppStyles.appPrimaryColor
                                      : AppStyles.appSecondaryColor,
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
                      })),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: SizeConfig.height20),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: SizeConfig.width10),
                child: TitleTextWidget(titleText: 'Service Address'),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: SizeConfig.height20),
              buildAddress(),
            ],
          ),
        );
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

pubspec.yaml

```
#Maps & Geolocator
  google_maps_flutter: ^2.1.8
  geolocator: ^8.2.0
  geocoding: ^2.0.4
  flutter_google_places: ^0.3.0
```

Comment: impossible to help without more information. 
what about version you are using - '2.10.3 Google Maps'??
it should be 'google_maps_flutter: ^2.1.3' (last is 'google_maps_flutter: ^2.1.8')

Comment: @VladyslavUlianytskyi I have upgraded my flutter version to 3.0.3 and my 'google_maps_flutter' version to 2.1.8 and the app still crashes when i load Google Maps.

Comment: Any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

make sure you specify your Google Maps API key like below:

[image]

Comment: This has been done. Like i mentioned. Everything worked perfectly with flutter 2.10.3

Comment: Is it crashing on both Android & iOS?

Comment: Yes. It crashes on both iOS and Android.

Answer (score 0):

Try following code:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';

class SearchPartnersView extends StatefulWidget {
  const SearchPartnersView({super.key});

  @override
  State<SearchPartnersView> createState() => _SearchPartnersViewState();
}

class _SearchPartnersViewState extends State<SearchPartnersView> {

  final Completer<GoogleMapController> _controller = Completer();
  //This controller is important;

  //Don't forget of calling the dispose method;
  @override
  void dispose() {
    _disposeController();
    super.dispose();
  }

  Future<void> _disposeController() async {
  final GoogleMapController controller = await _controller.future;
  controller.dispose();
}
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    CameraPosition vegasPosition = const CameraPosition(target: LatLng(36.0953103, -115.1992098), zoom: 10);
    return  Scaffold(
      body: SizedBox(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          child: GoogleMap(
            mapType: MapType.normal,
            initialCameraPosition: vegasPosition,
            onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
              _controller.complete(controller);
            },
          ),
        )
      );
    }
  }
```